# Program that edits own headers sends SEGFAULT after header-eraser function has finished

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I have been getting errors from GDB saying "../elf/dl-runtime.c:73 file not found" in the first external function called after SearchAndDestroy().
Here is the function

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define ELFHeaderLength 0x40
#define ProgramHeaderLength 0x38
#define SectionHeaderLength 0x40
#define AddressLength 12
#define SecondAddressOffset (AddressLength + 1)

#define FileLineBuff 150
typedef int WORD;

int SearchAndDestroy(void)
{
    FILE *filePointer;
    char line[FileLineBuff];
    char lastLine[FileLineBuff];
    char addressStr[AddressLength + 1];
    long int addressInt;
    WORD *start;
    WORD *end;

    // open /proc/self/maps file
    filePointer = fopen("/proc/self/maps", "r");
    if (filePointer == NULL)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    // read the first address from first line from /proc/self/maps into address array  
    fgets(line, FileLineBuff * sizeof(char), filePointer);
    memcpy(addressStr, line, AddressLength);
    addressStr[AddressLength] = 0x00;

    // make hex then make pointer
    addressInt = strtol(addressStr, NULL, 16);
    start = (WORD *) addressInt;

    // trace through until the last line is found
    for (; (strstr(line, "MangleS.elf")) != NULL; fgets(line, FileLineBuff * sizeof(char), filePointer))
    {
        memcpy(lastLine, line, FileLineBuff);
    }
    memcpy(addressStr, &lastLine[SecondAddressOffset], AddressLength);
    addressStr[AddressLength] = 0x00;

    // make hex then make pointer
    addressInt = strtol(addressStr, NULL, 16);
    end = (WORD *) addressInt;

    // close file stream
    fclose(filePointer);

    // allow write to header spaces with mprotect
    mprotect(start, ELFHeaderLength + ProgramHeaderLength, PROT_WRITE);

    // clear ELF & Program Headers
    for (int i = 0; i < (ELFHeaderLength + ProgramHeaderLength); i++)
    {
        *(start + i) = 0;
    }

    // disallow write & allow SectionHeader write
    mprotect(start, ELFHeaderLength + ProgramHeaderLength, PROT_READ);
    mprotect(end - SectionHeaderLength, SectionHeaderLength, PROT_WRITE);

    // clear Section Header
    for (int i = 0; i < SectionHeaderLength; i++)
    {
        *(end - SectionHeaderLength + i) = 0;
    }
    mprotect(end - SectionHeaderLength, SectionHeaderLength, PROT_READ);
    return 0;
}
```

Valgrind produced an error, Invalid Write Size of 4, near the end. Print statements show this doesn't happen during normal execution, though. GDB currently highlights an if statement in another function as the cause of the crash, but a print statement that should precede that if statement does not appear in normal execution.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to improve it, like showing a [mcve] (with emphasis on the ***minimal*** part).

Comment: I am voting to close this question for lack of focus on the actual problem. Too much explaining and code related to irrelevant things. (That is my reason for cving. Not, for example, that I resent helping with this kind of activity.)

Comment: @BraffZacklin `*(end - SectionHeaderLength + i) = 0;` crashes.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. The application/purpose of your program seems sensitive, and you should probably not share what your program does on the internet, especially because it is not relevant to the actual issue you are facing. Instead post a minimal code example which reproduces the issue, this will also show readers that you tried basic debugging and localized the problem

Comment: What do you mean? On my computer, zeroing out the headers didn't produce any crash, it was only after it moved onto other functions tthat various things started producing errors.

Comment: "Program that edits own headers". That's your problem right here. "It worked on my computer". Famous last words.

Comment: The first obvious error is that elf header sizes are in bytes, but you are using an `int` pointer to manipulate them. There are many other errors.

Comment: Either of those comments are just almost entirely unhelpful. I recognise there are errors, otherwise it wouldn't be erroring. I've run it on a different computer and the same thing happens. The function itself does not produce a crash. The segfault happens after the function is called.

Comment: OT: regarding: `fgets(line, FileLineBuff * sizeof(char), filePointer);`  the expression: `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect (and just clutters the code)  Suggest removing that expression.  always check the returned value (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: OT: regarding: `if (filePointer == NULL)
    {
        return 2;
    }`   strongly suggest the statement: `return 2;` be replaced with: `perror( "fopen failed" );   exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `addressStr[AddressLength] = 0x00;`  The call to `fgets()` will already have NUL terminated the string, and so no need to add a NUL byte

Comment: regarding; `end = (WORD *) addressInt;` and `start = (WORD *) addressInt;`  the variable `addressInt` is a `long int`, not a pointer

Comment: regarding statements like: `*(end - SectionHeaderLength + i) = 0;`  where that is writing in memory is NOT the details in `/prog/,,,` but rather at some 'random' location in your application memory

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think about any of that, actually. The reasoning for the return 2 is because I wanted the program to then shred & delete itself after, although all the same that is useful to know. I thought memcpy wouldn't nul terminate the string, though? I was having a strange thing happen where it printed out a junk ascii char then the next line, although strangely that isn't happening now. I can't remember what changed since, but that must have been an artifact from that fix.

Comment: Regarding /proc/self/maps, how would you go about reading it as a pointer? I can't for the life of me figure it out, and it looked like I had with that, but clearly not. It was hard to find anything online. Is there a different way to get a pointer to the start and end of the program?